# Every binary 'wine' executable "does not exist"

Tags: wine, executable

I've had this problem once before, but I completely forgot how I fixed it.

Every wine executable (/usr/bin/wine, or the wines in the playonlinux dir) "do not exist" when I try to execute them.

```
$ wine
bash: /usr/bin/wine: Bestand of map bestaat niet
```

Answer (score 1):

Knackered path? Wang `echo "$PATH"` into a terminal and see what it says. I expect something along the lines of:

```
/home/oli/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
```

The repo-installed `wine` lives in `/usr/bin` so if that segment of the path is missing, it's going to break things. That said, I'd expect that to break a whole lot more at the same time too. Perhaps the issue is so local because there's something squiffy in your `~/.bashrc`